# Integrate Google Optimize in Nuxt application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Google Optimize in my Nuxt application. I need a way to fire an activation event after any of the page components gets updated. The problem currently is there can be data that is being returned by API and using the API data the DOM gets re-rendered in page load. I need to fire the activation event after that. The google docs for firing activation events in SPA is given below
[Firing activation in a single page application](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7008840?#firing-in-single-page-apps)

For the angular app, it is accomplished by adding

```
myapp.run(function($rootScope, $timeout) {
   $rootScope.$watch(function(){
     $timeout(function(){
       dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate'});
     },0,false);
   })
})
```

I am looking for a similar kind of alternative in my Nuxt application

I know that inside a component, I can listen for the `updated` life cycle hook after content has been updated and DOM has been re-rendered. But I need a way to execute some code in a central place when any of the components got updated or DOM gets re-rendered.

What I have used is I created a global mixin (`globalMixin.js`) inside the `plugins` directory and used it's `updated` lifecycle method. So this mixin code gets injected into every component and the update method gets called if any of those component data gets changed. But I am doubting this approach as an ideal solution.

Can anyone suggest to me a better approach to doing this task or does Nuxt/Vue has any standard way of doing this? The code inside `plugins/globalMixin.js` is given below:

```
if (!Vue.__my_mixin__) {
      Vue.__my_mixin__ = true
      Vue.mixin({
        updated() {
        ..execute some code
       }
     }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a store such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to handle the local state of your application.

You can then retrieve the state of the store in any page or component. I recommend using [vuex-map-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-map-fields?activeTab=readme)

Comment: Sorry it is not like that, I need to execute some code when the DOM gets updated in the page.We normally use updated life cycle hook for this but this is only applicable to a component.A page contains a lots of component and if there is a hydration that is happening in any of the components in the page, I need to execute some code.Basically I am using Google optimize in my web application built with Nuxt. I need to fire an activation event when any of the component in page re renders.

Comment: You should update your question specifying how you have integrated google optimize in your application and explain a bit more what you try to do with it. I still think that vuex might be your solution here as you can catch any change of any component based on its state

Comment: There is a lot of components in the application, what I am looking for is I need to write code in a central place so that it works for future components also. Site already use vuex and if you specify vuex solution can you please specify how can I accomplish this task without touching up the n number of components used in the application. Google optimize implementation for Single page application is given in this link 

https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7008840?#firing-in-single-page-apps

Comment: Please look in the link for angular app implemention, it is just a few lines code so it works for entire app. I need that kind of an alternative in our application.Our application already uses vuex but is used for inter component communication

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite anything, maybe you could add a script to the whole app and use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You would not have to care about integrating google optimize with vuejs at all